# Is there a tool like Swagger for non API methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I have a project that consists of Web API methods that are on Swagger and that is fine.
The problem is that my login methods went from being in API Controller to classic MVC Controller.
I can call my method from a tool like Postman and it works. The thing is that I want the cookie that is created on the login method to be seen in the browser, when I call my API methods.
How can I do this? Is there some tool like Swagger for MVC Controller methods?

I need this for a purpose of testing the methods without frontend part.
So, I would call my method from MVC controller, it would set a cookie in a browser and then I would continue with my Swagger API

Comment: I think when it works is the login browser is still connected to server to when the API is called the login is still valid.  I suspect you are closing the login page before calling the API so the login is not valid.  You can check my theory by using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.

Comment: Postman is a separate app, so the cookies in it are not the same as the cookies in the browser

Comment: Non-API actions often involve views and possibly form posts, so that just doesn’t work as nicely as APIs which are designed to be mostly stateless. If you want to test your actions in your browser, the way to do it is to open their routes.

Comment: The cookies come from the server so they are the same.

Comment: I just tough that there is some tool in the browser like swagger so that QA won't need to use postman for the login method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done.
We ended up using Postman for this kind of methods.